# Как связать discord py и vk-api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, discord

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(1009917009175269417)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        vk.messages.send(f"{message.content}")
```

vk.messages.send(f"{message.content}")
TypeError: VkApiMethod.**call**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В библиотеке vk_api, немного по-другому вызывают метод messages.send:**

```
vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': 1, 'message': (f"{message.content}"), 'random_id': 0})
```

Вы забыли путь сообщения (chat_id или peer_id) и random_id.

Подробнее: https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send

Весь код:

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(1009917009175269417)
    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot:
        vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': 1, 'message': (f"{message.content}"), 'random_id': 0})
```